# less.js getting synchronous XMLHttpRequest error on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, less

Im new to LESS CSS and Chrome Extensions. All the LESS CSS is working in the extension, but this error persists. What am I doing wrong? This may sound trite, but as Im new to this, please answer with that in mind. Thanks!

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="styles.less" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="less.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2384 which suggests using `async: true` option. In your case it looks like you also need `fileAsync: true`. P.S. This is not an error, but a deprecation warning, so you can actually ignore it if the page isn't slowed down (use devtools to measure the timing).

Comment: Thanks again @wOxxOm! You've answered nearly all of my Extension questions I post on SO. "Mentored" in a strange way.